# get_by_key_name() in GAE taking as long as 750ms. Is this expected?

Tags: google-app-engine, appstats

My program fetches ~100 entries in a loop. All entries are fetched using get_by_key_name(). **Appstats show that some get_by_key_name() requests are taking as much as 750ms! (other big values are 355ms, 260ms, 230ms)**. Average for other fetches ranges from 30ms to 100ms. These times are in real_time and hence contribute towards 'ms' and not 'cpu_ms'.

Due to the above, **total time taken to return the webpage is very high ms=5754, where cpu_ms=1472**. (above times are seen repeatedly for back to back requests.)

**Environment:** Python 2.7, webapp2, jinja2, High Replication, No other concurrent requests to the server, Frontend Instance Class is F1, No memcache set yet, max idle instances is automatic, min pending latency is automatic, using db (NOT NDB).

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I based whole database design on fetching entries from the datastore using only get_by_key_name()!!

**Update:**
I tried **profiling using time.clock()** before and immediately after every get_by_key_name() method call. The difference I get from time.clock() for every single call is 10ms! (Just want to clarify that the get_by_key_name() is called on different Kinds).

According to time.clock() the total execution time (in wall-clock time) is 660ms. But the real-time is 5754 (=ms), and cpu_ms is 1472 per GAE logs.

**Summary of Questions:**

1. *[Update: This was addressed by passing list of keys] Why get_by_key_name() is taking that long?*
2. Why ms of 5754 is so much more than cpu_ms of 1472. Is task execution in halted/waiting-state for 75% (1-1472/5754) of the time due to which real-time (wall clock) time taken is so long as far as end user is concerned?
3. If the above is true, then why time.clock() shows that only 660ms (wall-clock time) elapsed between start of the first get_by_key_name() request and the last (~100th) get_by_key_name() request; although GAE shows this time as 5754ms?

Comment: You can pass a list of keys and that should go faster

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. Still wondering, is what I am seeing above normal for GAE as these times are impractical. Thanks again.

Comment: You will find fetching by key can be all over the place, though not normally that long.  You always want to batch you gets as much as possible, because it's the repeated round trip time that can build up.

Comment: Thanks Tim. By batching you mean passing list of keys as Daniel recommended. Correct? Further wondering, what explains Q#2 and #3 above. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm wondering if in your model you have repeated properties ? There's a known issue with the python version of app engine which makes deserialization of entities with repeated properties way too long. And by too long I mean you can literally have queries taking 30 or 40 seconds for a couple hundreds entities (but with many repeated properties). I don't know if this apply in your case, but could be.

Comment: @brian Thanks for the response. No repeated properties as such. I made code changes to pass a list of keys (as Daniel and Tim recommended) along with Memcache (add, and get). And now not really seeing 750ms delay. Looking forward to responses for #2 and #3. Thanks again.